# How to check whether a boolean value is false in every object of an array in?

Tags: typescript

I have an array which consists of multiple objects:

```
quesListArray = [
                   {Position: 1, Mandatory: false}, 
                   {Position: 2, Mandatory: true}, 
                   {Position: 3, Mandatory: false}, 
                   ...
                   ...
                ]
```

How can I get to know whether 'Mandatory' field in every object is false or not. If all are false then I need to show a message.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: how is this question related to Angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every#Syntax) with arrow function (for brevity) on `questListArray`, like so:

```
areAllMandatoriesFalse() {
   if (this.quesListArray.every(item => !item.Mandatory)) {
     alert("All are false");
   }
   else {
      alert("Not all are false");
   }
}
```

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1mw5ta)

Comment: @Mr.A: please do practise to upvote the answer if helpfull and mark as accepted if answer is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

use 'every'.
for example:

```
function isBelowThreshold(currentValue) {
    return currentValue < 40;
}

var array = [1, 30, 39, 29, 10, 13];

console.log(array.every(isBelowThreshold));
// expected output: true
```

I hope my help is effective ツ

Comment: I already suggested using "every". In less than 4 min two upvotes are suspisious

Comment: I got into this problem today at the company. I answered this answer and two of my colleagues liked it... :)   
@Vega

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
checkPropAreFalse() {
    let MandatoryFlag = true;
    for (let index = 0; index < this.quesListArray.length; index++) {
      const element = this.quesListArray[index];
      if (!element.Mandatory) {
        continue;
      } else {
        MandatoryFlag = false;
        break;
      }
    }
    return MandatoryFlag;
  }
```

Call Method from your file:

```
const responce = this.checkPropAreFalse();
```